# Mock getInstance() of a singleton to return child class (Quarkus)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, singleton, quarkus

I am trying to mock getInstance() of a singleton class below to return a mocked class instead:

1. Base class (**passo9()** is the method to be mocked):

```java
package br.com.bb.ids.robo.passo09;

import br.com.bb.ids.robo.passo09.dao.RoboSkipDao;
import br.com.bb.ids.robo.passo09.exceptions.RoboSkipDaoFindException;
import br.com.bb.ids.robo.passo09.exceptions.RoboSkipDaoMergeException;
import br.com.bb.ids.robo.passo09.models.RoboSkip;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class Motor {
    private static Motor instance;
    
    public static Motor getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Motor();
        }
        
        return instance;
    }
    
    private Motor() {}

    /**
     * Method to be mocked
     * 
     * @return error code (0 if successful)
     * @throws Exception any non expected exception
     */
    public int passo9() throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("Verifica o ponto onde o robô parou");
            RoboSkipDao rsDao = RoboSkipDao.getInstance();
            RoboSkip rs = rsDao.findByPasso(9);
            int resultadoPasso = Integer.parseInt(rs.getValor());
            
            rs.setValor(Integer.toString(resultadoPasso + 32768));
            rsDao.merge(rs);
        }
        catch (RoboSkipDaoFindException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao consultar registro em robo_skip, passo = 9.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 2;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Número do registro inválido em robo_skip, passo 9.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 3;
        }
        catch (RoboSkipDaoMergeException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao atualizar registro em robo_skip, passo 9.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 8;
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
}
```

2. The extended class to be called instead of **Motor** above:

```java
package br.com.bb.ids.robo.passo09;

import io.quarkus.test.Mock;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@Mock
@ApplicationScoped
public class MotorMock extends Motor {
    public MotorMock(Motor m) {}
    
    @Override
    public int passo9() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("passo9() mockado - return 0");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

3. The Quarkus **main** class (**Motor.getInstance()** should return **MotorMock** instead of **Motor** in my test below):

```java
package br.com.bb.ids.robo.passo09;

import io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus;
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.QuarkusMain;

@QuarkusMain
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1 || !args[0].matches("true|false")) {
            System.err.println("Indicação em desenvolvimento (true/false) obrigatória.");
            return;
        }
        boolean emDesenvolvimento = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[0]);
        
        System.out.println("Iniciando aplicação...");
        try {
            Motor motor = Motor.getInstance();
            motor.setEmDesenvolvimento(emDesenvolvimento);
            
            int returnCode = motor.passo9();
            System.out.println("Finalizando aplicação...");
            Quarkus.asyncExit(returnCode);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
}
```

4. My test module:

```java
package br.com.bb.ids.robo.passo09;

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusMock;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@QuarkusTest
public class MainTest {
    @Inject
    Motor motor;
    
    @Test
    public void testMain() {
        MotorMock mm = new MotorMock(Motor.getInstance());
        Mockito.when(((Motor)mm).getInstance()).thenReturn(mm);
        QuarkusMock.installMockForType(mm, Motor.class);
        
        System.out.println("Testando Main.main(args)...");
        String[] args = new String[1];
        args[0] = "true";
        Main.main(args);
        System.out.println("Testes com Main.main(args) efetuados com sucesso.");
    }   
}
```

I want to call **MotorMock.passo9()** instead of **Motor.passo9()** inside my test case. How do I achieve this? If possible, share with code example.

Comment: You shouldn't annotate `MotorMock` with `@Mock` or `@ApplicationScoped`. Can you remove them and try again?

Comment: First of all, get rid of the `getInstance()` method. Never programmatically instantiate classes that are supposed to be managed by the CDI container. Instead, use `@Inject`, or if you'd really have to, `CDI.current()`. Then, `QuarkusMock.installMockForType` should work.

Comment: @Ladicek I really have to use `getInstance()` on this class (no way to get rid of it). I would like, if possible, see an coded example of `CDI.current()` together with `QuarkusMock.installMockForType`.

Comment: I'm 100% sure it is possible to get rid of manually instantiating the class. Worst case is that your `getInstance` method would look like this: `return CDI.current().select(Motor.class).get()`. However, in vast majority of cases, you can get rid of this and use `@Inject`, producer methods etc. The point is: you declared your class as a bean (`@ApplicationScoped`), so you should let the CDI container manage its lifecycle (that's also why mocking can actually work) and never ever instantiate it manually.